# how to open modal on load of page by typing the url of particular template

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

how to open the modal pop up just by typing url link without any click function.
here i'm trying to open modal without logging in by typing url but modal appears for few seconds and it disappears. If logged-in, email and passowrd is present in localstorage, modal opens. Here i need modal to be opened even without logged in and even if no email and password is present in localstorage.

### reset.html

```html
<div bsModal  *ngIf="isModalShown" [config]="{ show: true }"  #resetPwd="bs-modal" (onHidden)="onHidden()" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Reset Password</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### reset.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './reset.html'
})

export class ResetComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
  @ViewChild('resetPwd') public resetPwd:ModalDirective;

  public isModalShown: boolean = true;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.showModal();
  }

  showModal(){
    this.isModalShown = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/reset']);
    this.resetPwd.show();
    console.log(this.isModalShown);
   
  }
  onHidden(){
    this.isModalShown = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    this.resetPwd.hide();
    console.log(this.isModalShown);

  }
}
```

Comment: So some how you are telling isModalShow property is changed from true to false , can you replicate this hard to guess it out here. the best would have been to go with router resolver

Comment: i tried in this way but its not working. is their any other way than this to open modal on typing url

Comment: Yes i would say go for router resolver this would be better check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard)

Comment: thank u, but in simple way can the modal be opened by typung url ???

Comment: by typing url in the address bar right ?

Comment: yes.. by typing url navigating to reset component, modal should open

Comment: Yes you can so this via resolver which will be invoked before the component is rendered and you can show it

Comment: If u got any answers can you post it. it would be helpful for me

Comment: that links shows you about resolvers i have to make one as of now i dnt

Comment: ok thanks for that i'l try on that.

Answer (score 0):

I use UI-Router so setup and state definitions are not an exact match to the built in router, but I believe the following mechanisms are available in built in router too: I’d recommend defining a state for the modal view in particular? Even set your “background view” as a parent view to display modal over the background. This would give you a URL path specifically for the modal view you’re after.